# Higher order expectation of Lévy process using Teugels martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, levy-processes

I am new about stochastic calculus but I would like to know if the following procedure for computing $E\left(L^{2}_{t}\right)$ and $E\left(L^{3}_{t}\right)$ if $L_{t}$ is a Lévy pure jump process is correct.

The assumptions considered are  $\int^{t}_{0}E\left(\left|L^3_{u}\right|^2\right)du<+\infty$ and $E\left[L_1\right]=0$. Using integration by parts I get:

$$
L_{t}^{2}=2\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}dL_{u}+\left[L,L\right]_{0}^{t}.
$$

Recalling the Teugels martingales $\bar{L}_{t}^{\left(i\right)}=\sum_{0<h\leq t}\left(\Delta L_{h}\right)^{i}-m_{i}t,\ \ \ i\geq1$ with $m_1=0$ and $i\geq2
 , m_{i}=\int x^{i}d\nu_{L}\left(x\right)
 $ ($\nu_{L}$ Lévy measure), the quadratic variation can be written as:

$$
\left[L,L\right]_{0}^{t}=\bar{L}_{t}^{\left(2\right)}+m_2 t,
$$

then 
$$
L_{t}^{2}=2\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}dL_{u}+\bar{L}_{t}^{\left(2\right)}+m_2 t.
$$
Take the expectation of both sides of the equation and get:
$$
E\left[L_{t}^{2}\right] = m_2 t.
$$

For computing the quantity $E\left(L^{3}_{t}\right)$, I apply the integration by parts to the process $L^3_t=L_t*L_t^2$:
$$
L_{t}^{3}=\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}^{2}dL_{u}+\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}dL_{u}^{2}+\left[2\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}dL_{u}+\left[L,L\right]_{0}^{t},L\right]_{0}^{t}
$$ 
Using the definition of quadratic covariation I get
$$
\left[\left[L,L\right],L\right]_{0}^{t}=\sum_{0<h\leq t}\Delta\left[L,L\right]_{h}\Delta L_{h}
$$
 now $\Delta\left[L,L\right]_{h}=\sum_{0<s\leq h}\left(\Delta L_{s}\right)^{2}-\sum_{0<s<h}\left(\Delta L_{s}\right)^{2}=\left(\Delta L_{h}\right)^{2}$ 
 then 
$$
\left[\left[L,L\right],L\right]_{0}^{t}=\sum_{0<h\leq t}\left(\Delta L_{h}\right)^{3}=\bar{L}_{t}^{\left(3\right)}+m_{3}t
$$
where $\bar{L}_{t}^{\left(3\right)}$
  is Teugels Martingales associated to the process $\sum_{0<h\leq t}\left(\Delta L_{h}\right)^{3}$. Rewrite  $L^3_t$ as:
$$
L_{1}^{3}=\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}^{2}dL_{u}+2\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}^{2}dL_{u}+\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}d\bar{L}_{u}^{\left(2\right)}+m_{2}*\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}du+2\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}d\left[L,L\right]_{u}+\left[\left[L,L\right],L\right]_{0}^{t}=
$$
$$
=3\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}^{2}dL_{u}+3\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}d\bar{L}_{u}^{\left(2\right)}+3m_{2}\int_{0}^{t}L_{u-}du+\bar{L}_{t}^{\left(3\right)}+m_{3}t
$$
Computing the expectation of both sides I have $E\left(L_{1}^{3}\right)=m_{3}$.

Comment: Looks fine to me. :)